# Stop function from being ran again if still running

Tags: python

I've got a python script which calls a function and I want to have a cronjob run it every 5 minutes.

```
def colour_images(images=None):
    ...
    os.system("command")
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    colour_images()
```

It runs a command to the terminal using os I want to know if the task is completed (no similar task is running) before running the command.

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen.communicate` instead. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: So you basically want your script to check if there is a python script running from the same location and with the same name as itself?

Answer (score 0):

Write a dummy lock file when starting the job and delete it when done. Then you can check whatever the lock file exist or not to decide to run the script again.

If the date and time on the file is older than 10+ minutes just delete it to protect against some error causing the file not been deleted

Comment: I went with this too & I upvoted it. I didn't add the option to delete the file just to see how frequently it might get stuck.